# How to generate unique url like g2a.com after your purchase?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello Guys I'm doing a simple project for website and i just found something interesting at g2a.com after your purchase they generate url automatically send to your mail like theses "screenshots"

[screenshot number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lnRN.png)

[screenshot number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbsCF.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Send mail with purchase information (quantity ...) and a link like the following

```
http://youtsiteexemple.com/purchase.php?purchase_id=123
```

you can add the following to add hash data for secure purchase

```
http://youtsiteexemple.com/purchase.php?purchase_id=123&token=D1GF323
```